# VB.NET - How do i concatenate a Control name with another variable value to change it's properties?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to change the properties (Example: ReadOnly, BorderStyle, Forecolor...) of the textbox referenced in "with".

```
Private Sub Apply(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txt10.KeyDown, txt0.KeyDown

   If txt10.ReadOnly = False Then
      If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

         With txt10
         .ForeColor = Color.White
         .ReadOnly = True
         .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
         End With

      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

The thing is, I need to set these properties to a certain textbox, so I've declared a variable called "Number", and I was thinking if this could work:

```
With Controls("txt" & Number)
         .ForeColor = Color.White
         .ReadOnly = True
         .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
         End With
```

This only works for some properties, and don't work with the "with". Do you have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Try `With Controls("txt" & Number)`, without the dot.

Comment: My bad, I did without the dot in visual studio, I will edit the question. This method didn't work by the way.

Comment: It says "'ReadOnly' is not a member of 'Controls'". The same applies to the BorderStyle

Comment: Anu6is has it, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the control and define it as a TextBox. Then utilize it just as you did before. When you get a control from teh `Controls` collection, because the control type is not specified, some properties will not be available (example the textbox readonly property).

```vb
Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(Controls("txt" & number), TextBox)

If textBox.ReadOnly = False AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    With textBox
        .ForeColor = Color.White
        .ReadOnly = True
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  :-)

Comment: For RBarryYoung: It worked! Thanks for showing this method! 

For Craig: I can try your way, but the other guy's idea worked for me.

Comment: It would be best to define the TextBox this way: `Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender As TextBox)`. This way, no `number` variable needs to be tracked, and the Sub will work for any additional TextBoxes the event handler may handle later on.